# MFMailComposeViewController disappear immediately under iOS9

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios9, xcode7.1beta

Once I present my `MFMailComposeViewController` it is dismissed with error:

> viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

What is going on?

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE**

It is working very well under `iOS8`.

Answer (score 0):

i can't help you since you did not post any code, but here is a working copy of a MailComposeController  on iOS9, using it in my app without any problem. **Important**  set your class conform to MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate. Note that sendMail method is related to a button in my project

```
@IBAction func sendMail(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}


func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self 
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["yourMail@goesHere"])

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {

   print("There was an error.")
    //In case of error with email account on device, you should implement an alert here

}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```